# Sort <table> by multiple <tbody>'s

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table, tablesorter, listjs

I need to sort my `<table>` by grouped multiple `<tbody>`'s

It's pretty straight forward and looks like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="listing-1">
        <tr>
            <td>Blue widget</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="listing-2">
        <tr>
            <td>Red Widget</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="listing-3">
        <tr>
            <td>Blue widget</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm grouping each listing in a `<tbody>` and want to sort the table having the two `<tr>`'s in each `<tbody>` locked together.

If I sort by the Header 1 to get the `<td>`'s with Blue widget on top, I need the whole of each `<tbody>` to move up, so it looks like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="listing-1">
        <tr>
            <td>Blue widget</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="listing-3">
        <tr>
            <td>Blue widget</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="listing-2">
        <tr>
            <td>Red Widget</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I've been using ListJS (http://listjs.com/) to sort my tables, but it doesn't appear to support grouping tbody's like this. I then checked out TableSorter (https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/), but that doesn't appear to support it either.

I am at a loss on how to sort this, but I'm thinking I can't be the only one ever wanting to do something like this. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question?

Any help or suggestion on how to do this, or which plugin to use, would be really awesome.

EDIT: Criteria for sorting is the first of each  in each . The second  in each  need to be locked together with the first  in each, and not sortable. So the second  is not ever supposed to be sortable, but instead should be locked in with the first .

Let me know if I'm still not making myself clear, and I'll try again.

Comment: sort by what criteria?

Comment: Sorting should be by each of the columns in the first <tr> in each <tbody>. The second <tr> in each <tbody> should just be "locked"  together (associated) with the first, and merely follow along. The colspan column should never be sortable. Sorry for not making that clear

Comment: The fork of tablesorter you tried does sort the content within each separate tbody - the [configuration table](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#Configuration) in the documents is proof of that. If you want to sort the tbodies themselves, the use the [`sortTbodies` widget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-sort-tbodies.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's not very clear what the sort criteria is. Assuming it is the number in second cell can do something like:

```js
var $tBodies = $('tbody').sort(function(a, b){     
         var aVal = +($(a).find('tr:first td').eq(1).text().trim() || 0); 
         var bVal = +($(b).find('tr:first td').eq(1).text().trim() || 0);            
         return aVal - bVal;
    });
    
    $('table').append($tBodies);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="listing-1">
        <tr>
            <td>Blue widget</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="listing-3">
        <tr>
            <td>Blue widget</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="listing-2">
        <tr>
            <td>Red Widget</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">text</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've edited my post to clarify criteria.

Comment: Here's a better working version using clcik on headings. http://plnkr.co/edit/OxRG92A0RQrGeP0vTWs3?p=preview. Also has secondary sort using alternate cell for text or numbers that are equal

Comment: Did you just create this for me? If so, wow. I appreciate the effort mate, thanks very much.